# Missing assembly reference Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, .net-assembly

I installed Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate and I encounter painful build problems. Solutions cannot build, because of

```
Error  12  The type or namespace name 'TypeName' does not exist in the namespace 'Framework' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

The assembly is there for sure and is referenced - the only change was new VS - previously I used VS 2010 Ultimate. Also the target framework of both assembly and solution is the same (4.0.3).

Any solutions?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `The assembly is there for sure`. You still have to reference the assembly. Having the DLL in the file system is not enough.

Comment: Thank you, but the assembly is referenced. The issue is curious, because it worked in VS 2010, but installation of VS2012 broke something, because now in 2010 it also doesn't work.

Comment: Any new information about it? I'm also having the same problem.

Comment: Try Clean Solution and then rebuild..

Comment: Also try to Build only 1 project in your solution which does not have any dependencies to other projects and see if that builds and then try Rebuilding the whole solution...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have this line included:

```
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
```

If that doesn't help, this link might: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.typename.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The dll project and its referencing windows/console project should be in two independent folders.If these folders overlap the above problem comes.That means one project folder should not be inside other project folder.This problem coming only in vs2012 and vs2013